# Reset all modifications done to data by pressing an actionButton() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which I have 3 tabs. In the 1st tab I see raw data,in the second i click `Apply` to see a table with the variables and their class and select one of them and convert it to another class. In the 3rd tab I see the new data. Now I want to be able by pushing the reset button to bring the data in its inital form ready for a new process.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(stringr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Process"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("reset", "Reset", style = "width: 155px; height: 55px; color: #fff; background-color: #0dc5c1; border-color: #0dc5c1; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 10px;")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Raw data preview", box(title = "Raw data", status = "primary", width = 12, dataTableOutput("raw",width = 1600))),
      tabPanel("Change Variable Types",
               fluidRow(column(12, box(title = "Variable Type Processing", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                                       fluidRow(column(12,
                                                       dataTableOutput("TypeTable"))),
                                       fluidRow(
                                         column(4, uiOutput("selVarChan")),
                                         column(4, uiOutput("setVarType")),
                                         column(4, uiOutput("apply3"))
                                       ))))
      ),
      tabPanel("Processed Data Review",
               box(title = "Processed Data", status = "primary", width = 12, dataTableOutput("processedData")),
      )
    )
  )
)




server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  # UI outputs for header, separator, and quote based on file type
  
  
  # Reactive expression for file data
  file_info <- reactive({
    data<-structure(list(`Patient MRN` = c(20238782, 20290640), `Stainless Steel Crowns` = c(8, 
                                                                                             8), `Zirconia Crowns` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), `Canine Zirconia` = c(2, 
                                                                                                                                                                  0), Overbite...5 = c(0.5, 0), Overjet...6 = c("1mm", "0mm"), 
                         `Canine overlap` = c("2mm", "1mm"), `Posterior open bite` = c("N", 
                                                                                       "N"), Overbite...9 = c(0, 0), Overjet...10 = c("2mm", "0mm"
                                                                                       ), `Canine Overlap...11` = c("1mm", "-1mm"), `Posterior Open Bite...12` = c("N", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "N"), Overbite...13 = c(0, 0), Overjet...14 = c("0", "1mm"
                                                                                                                                                                   ), `Canine Overlap...15` = c("2mm", "1mm"), `Posterior Open Bite...16` = c("N", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "N"), `Change in Overbite` = c(0, 0), `Change in Canine Overlap (mm)` = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2), `Change Score` = c(1, 1), Date = c("45139", "45145"), 
                         Overbite...21 = c(NA, NA), Overjet...22 = c(NA, NA), `Canine Overlap...23` = c(NA, 
                                                                                                        NA), `Posterior Open Bite...24` = c(NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                    -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  })
  
  # Display the entire dataset without using 'disp' option
  output$raw <- renderDataTable({ 
    datatable(file_info(), options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE))
  })
  
  # Reactive value to hold the modified dataset
  modifiedData <- reactiveVal()
  
  # Initially, modifiedData is the same as the uploaded file data
  observe({
    modifiedData(file_info())
  })
  
  # Render raw data table
  output$raw <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(modifiedData(), options = list(pageLength = 5, searching = TRUE,scrollX='400px'))
  })
  
  #Check variables types table
  output$VarTypes<-renderDataTable({
    req(file_info())
    data<-data.frame(file_info())
    # Extract variable names and their classes
    variable_names <- names(data)
    variable_types <- sapply(data,class)
    
    # Create a new data frame
    variable_info_df <- data.frame(
      Variable = variable_names,
      Type = variable_types
    )
    datatable(variable_info_df,rownames = F
              
    )
  })
  
  # Selector for variables to change type
  output$selVarChan <- renderUI({
    req(modifiedData())
    pickerInput(
      "svc",
      "Select Variable to change class",
      choices = colnames(modifiedData()),
      multiple = F,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    )
  })
  #Actionbutton for change variable type
  output$apply3<-renderUI({
    req(modifiedData())
    actionButton("applyTypeChange", "Apply", class = "btn-primary")
  })
  # Selector for the new type
  output$setVarType <- renderUI({
    req(modifiedData())
    pickerInput(
      "svt",
      "Convert selected variable to:",
      choices = c("character", "factor", "numeric"),
      selected = "character",
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  })
  
  # Button to apply the type change
  observeEvent(input$applyTypeChange, {
    req(input$svc, input$svt, modifiedData())
    data <- modifiedData()
    
    for (var in input$svc) {
      data[[var]] <- switch(input$svt,
                            "character" = as.character(data[[var]]),
                            "factor" = as.factor(data[[var]]),
                            "numeric" = as.numeric(str_extract(data[[var]], "\\d+")),
                            data[[var]] # default case to avoid accidental conversion
      )
    }
    
    # Update the modified data with the new types
    modifiedData(data)
    
    # Trigger re-rendering of the DataTable to reflect type changes
    output$TypeTable <- renderDataTable({
      df <- modifiedData()
      variable_info_df <- data.frame(
        Variable = names(df),
        Type = sapply(df, class),
        `Number of NAs` = sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
      )
      datatable(variable_info_df, options = list(pageLength = 5), rownames = FALSE)
    })
  })
  
  # Reactive value to hold the processed data
  processedData <- reactiveVal()
  
  # Initially, processedData is the same as the uploaded file data
  observe({
    processedData(file_info())
  })
  
  # Update processedData when type changes or imputation is applied
  observeEvent(input$applyTypeChange, {
    processedData(modifiedData())
  })
  
  output$processedData <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(processedData(), options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE))
    
  })  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `observeEvent(input$reset, {
  modifiedData(file_info())
  processedData(file_info())
})`